# Reading the JSON hierarchy (Number of subnodes can be any number) file using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, recursion, automation, windows-scripting

Reading the JSON hierarchy (Number of subnodes can be any number) file using Powershell.
I could do it for one level but need the same for N number of loops and nested loops
Need result in Tree view, if not possible then Tabular way with the title on top of the root table

Below is the script so far I have developed:

```
$Filepath = 'C:\Users\Learner\Test2.JSON'
$JsonContent=gc $Filepath | ConvertFrom-Json
$RootNodeCount=$JsonContent.psobject.Properties.name.Count
$RootNodeName=$JsonContent.psobject.Properties.name
foreach ($Name in $RootNodeName) {Echo $Name-->  $JsonContent.$Name}
```

JSON File

```
{
    "foundation": {
        "network": {
            "resource_group_name": "rg-network-e2",
            "name": "nonprodvnet-e2"
        },
        "diagnostics": {
            "resource_group_name": "rg-mgmt-cu",
            "storage_account_name": "Sreacnt-e2"
        },
        "log_analytics": {
            "resource_group_name": "rg-mgmt-cu",
            "workspace_name": "la-sap-e2"
        },
        "recovery_vault": {
            "resource_group_name": "rg-mgmt-cu",
            "name": "rsv-sap-e2"
        },
        "windows_domain": {
            "domain_name": "dmn.local",
            "ou_path": "CN=Computers,DC=example,DC=com",
            "domain_user": "svc_domainjoin@dmn.local",
            "domain_password": "Pwd01"
        }
    },
    "control_flags": {
        "enable_boot_diagnostics": true,
        "enable_oms": false,
        "enable_backup": true,
        "windows_domain_join": false
    },
    "deployment": {
        "resource_group": {
            "name": "rg-sap-501-e2",
            "location": "eastus2"
        },
        "tags": {
            "owner": "for SAP"
        },
        "os_account": {
            "admin_username": "locadm"
        },
        "proximity_placement_groups": {
            "ppg-501": {}
        },
        "availability_sets": {
            "avset-cs-501": {
                "ppg_name": "ppg-501"
            },
            "avset-app-501": {
                "ppg_name": "ppg-501"
            },
            "avset-db-501": {
                "ppg_name": "ppg-501"
            }
        },
        "load_balancers": {
            "ilb-sap-501": {
                "dv2ascs": {
                    "ip_address": "192.0.18.20",
                    "probe_port": 62000,
                    "subnet": "app"
                },
                "dv2-ers": {
                    "ip_address": "192.0.18.21",
                    "probe_port": 62102,
                    "subnet": "app"
                }
            },
            "ilb-db-501": {
                "dv2-hana": {
                    "ip_address": "192.0.17.12",
                    "probe_port": 62503,
                    "subnet": "db"
                }
            }
        },
        "server_groups": {
            "ascs": {
                "os_type": "linux",
                "sku": "Standard_E4s_v3",
                "availability_set": "avset-cs-501",
                "backup_policy": "sap",
                "ppg_name": "ppg-501",
                "lb_refs": [
                    "dv2-ascs",
                    "dv2-ers"
                ],
                "os_disk_size": "30",
                "enable_accelerated_networking": true,
                "hosts": {
                    "vcs501-01": {
                        "nics": [
                            [
                                "192.0.18.18"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "vcs501-02": {
                        "nics": [
                            [
                                "192.0.18.19"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "subnet": "app",
                "image_details": {
                    "resource_id": null,
                    "marketplace_reference": {
                        "publisher" : "SUSE",
                        "offer"     : "sles-sap-15-sp1",
                        "sku"       : "gen1",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
                },
                "disks": [
                    {
                        "name": "usrsap",
                        "disk_size": "128",
                        "number_of_disks": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "apps": {
                "type": "app_linux",
                "os_type": "linux",
                "sku": "Standard_E4s_v3",
                "availability_set": "avset-app-501",
                "backup_policy": "sap",
                "ppg_name": "ppg-501",
                "enable_accelerated_networking": true,
                "os_disk_size": "30",
                "hosts": {
                    "vas501-01": {
                        "nics": [
                            [
                                "192.0.18.16",
                                "192.0.18.26"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "vas501-02": {
                        "nics": [
                            [
                                "192.0.18.17",
                                "192.0.18.27"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "subnet": "app",
                "image_details": {
                    "resource_id": null,
                    "marketplace_reference": {
                        "publisher" : "SUSE",
                        "offer"     : "sles-15-sp1",
                        "sku"       : "gen1",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
                },
                "disks": [
                    {
                        "name": "usrsap",
                        "disk_size": "128",
                        "number_of_disks": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hana": {
                "os_type": "linux",
                "sku": "Standard_E32s_v3",
                "availability_set": "avset-db-501",
                "backup_policy": "sap",
                "ppg_name": "ppg-501",
                "os_disk_size": "30",
                "subnet": "db",
                "lb_refs": [
                    "dv2-hana"
                ],
                "hosts": {
                    "vhs501-01": {
                        "nics": [
                            [
                                "192.0.17.10"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "vhs501-02": {
                        "nics": [
                            [
                                "192.0.17.11"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "image_details": {
                    "resource_id": null,
                    "marketplace_reference": {
                        "publisher" : "SUSE",
                        "offer"     : "sles-sap-15-sp1",
                        "sku"       : "gen1",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
                },
                "disks": [
                    {
                        "name": "usrsap",
                        "disk_size": "128",
                        "number_of_disks": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "hanashared",
                        "disk_size": "128",
                        "number_of_disks": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "hanadata",
                        "disk_size": "128",
                        "number_of_disks": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "hanalog",
                        "disk_size": "128",
                        "number_of_disks": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "hanabackup",
                        "disk_size": "512",
                        "number_of_disks": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really reading a [`Json`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) file but actually the hierarchy of a PowerShell object which might hold a lot of (.Net) object types but in this case it is limited by the original Json structure which only consists out of three major types:

- **Arrays**, containing multiple child objects
- [**PSCustomObjects**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7) (unless you use the [`ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter), containing child objects assigned to a specific name.
- [**Primitives**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) (including strings), which is basically an object ("*leaf*") without children.

To best way to read through a hierarchic structure of an unknown depth is to use a [`recursive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function, meaning a function that calls itself. To give you an example for your specific question:

```
Function Show-Object ($Object, $Depth = 0, $Name) {
    $Indent = if ($Depth++) { "    " * ($Depth - 2) }
    if ($Object -is [Array]) {
        If ($Name) { "$Indent$Name =" }
        foreach ($Item in $Object) {
            Show-Object $Item $Depth
        }
    }
    elseif ($Object -is [PSCustomObject]) {
        If ($Name) { "$Indent$Name =" }
        foreach ($Name in $Object.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
            Show-Object $Object.$Name $Depth $Name
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($Name) { "$Indent$Name = $Object" } else { "$Indent$Object" }
    }
}
```

As you can see, where the structure might any child objects (in case of an `[Array]` or an `[PSCustomObject]`), the `Show-Object` function is calling itself with a child object as the new input object, and some additional parameters as to e.g. keep track of the current `$Depth`.

You can call the function simply like:

```
Show-Object $JsonContent
```

Or export it to a file like:

```
Show-Object $JsonContent | Out-File .\text1.txt
```

For your `$JsonContent` it will result in:

```
foundation =
    network =
        resource_group_name = rg-network-e2
        name = nonprodvnet-e2
    diagnostics =
        resource_group_name = rg-mgmt-cu
        storage_account_name = Sreacnt-e2
    log_analytics =
        resource_group_name = rg-mgmt-cu
        workspace_name = la-sap-e2
    recovery_vault =
        resource_group_name = rg-mgmt-cu
        name = rsv-sap-e2
    windows_domain =
        domain_name = dmn.local
        ou_path = CN=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
        domain_user = svc_domainjoin@dmn.local
        domain_password = Pwd01
control_flags =
    enable_boot_diagnostics = True
    enable_oms = False
    enable_backup = True
    windows_domain_join = False
deployment =
    resource_group =
        name = rg-sap-501-e2
        location = eastus2
    tags =
        owner = for SAP
    os_account =
        admin_username = locadm
    proximity_placement_groups =
        ppg-501 =
    availability_sets =
        avset-cs-501 =
            ppg_name = ppg-501
        avset-app-501 =
            ppg_name = ppg-501
        avset-db-501 =
            ppg_name = ppg-501
    load_balancers =
        ilb-sap-501 =
            dv2ascs =
                ip_address = 192.0.18.20
                probe_port = 62000
                subnet = app
            dv2-ers =
                ip_address = 192.0.18.21
                probe_port = 62102
                subnet = app
        ilb-db-501 =
            dv2-hana =
                ip_address = 192.0.17.12
                probe_port = 62503
                subnet = db
    server_groups =
        ascs =
            os_type = linux
            sku = Standard_E4s_v3
            availability_set = avset-cs-501
            backup_policy = sap
            ppg_name = ppg-501
            lb_refs =
                dv2-ascs
                dv2-ers
            os_disk_size = 30
            enable_accelerated_networking = True
            hosts =
                vcs501-01 =
                    nics =
                            192.0.18.18
                vcs501-02 =
                    nics =
                            192.0.18.19
            subnet = app
            image_details =
                resource_id =
                marketplace_reference =
                    publisher = SUSE
                    offer = sles-sap-15-sp1
                    sku = gen1
                    version = latest
            disks =
                    name = usrsap
                    disk_size = 128
                    number_of_disks = 1
        apps =
            type = app_linux
            os_type = linux
            sku = Standard_E4s_v3
            availability_set = avset-app-501
            backup_policy = sap
            ppg_name = ppg-501
            enable_accelerated_networking = True
            os_disk_size = 30
            hosts =
                vas501-01 =
                    nics =
                            192.0.18.16
                            192.0.18.26
                vas501-02 =
                    nics =
                            192.0.18.17
                            192.0.18.27
            subnet = app
            image_details =
                resource_id =
                marketplace_reference =
                    publisher = SUSE
                    offer = sles-15-sp1
                    sku = gen1
                    version = latest
            disks =
                    name = usrsap
                    disk_size = 128
                    number_of_disks = 1
        hana =
            os_type = linux
            sku = Standard_E32s_v3
            availability_set = avset-db-501
            backup_policy = sap
            ppg_name = ppg-501
            os_disk_size = 30
            subnet = db
            lb_refs =
                dv2-hana
            hosts =
                vhs501-01 =
                    nics =
                            192.0.17.10
                vhs501-02 =
                    nics =
                            192.0.17.11
            image_details =
                resource_id =
                marketplace_reference =
                    publisher = SUSE
                    offer = sles-sap-15-sp1
                    sku = gen1
                    version = latest
            disks =
                    name = usrsap
                    disk_size = 128
                    number_of_disks = 1
                    name = hanashared
                    disk_size = 128
                    number_of_disks = 1
                    name = hanadata
                    disk_size = 128
                    number_of_disks = 3
                    name = hanalog
                    disk_size = 128
                    number_of_disks = 2
                    name = hanabackup
                    disk_size = 512
                    number_of_disks = 1
```

Comment: Wonderful, Could you please also help me with a way to export this data to a file.

Comment: You can simply export this a file using the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet: `Show-Object $JsonContent | Out-File .\MyFlie.txt`

Comment: Nice recursion.  I wonder if there should be a different kind of compare-object that's more like a json diff that recursively lists all the differences, which some people expect in the first place.

Comment: @js2010, thanks for the comments  (please, up-vote ☺). I have thought of creating a "`Compare-ComplexObject`" before but I don't think it belongs in this question. I will give it some more thought and if I do write it, I will notify you.

Comment: @iRon Could you please add a procedure to represent it in a tabular way

Comment: Please, create a new stackoverflow question for this (you might refer to this one) and detai (e.g. with an example)l what you mean with "*tabular way*" also make sure that your question is unique. Note that stackoverflow in not for letting some write your code (unless it is reusable) but to help you to write your own code. If you need somebody to write code for you, you might want to try: https://codementor.io/powershell-experts